# Null Reference exception in FirstOrDefault C#

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I have this line:

```
myobject.Ada = result.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == "Ada No").Value;
```

Sometimes result doesn't have "Ada No" and I get

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I wrote an if statement to avoid null reference exception :

```
if(result.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == "Ada No").Value != null)
{
   myobject.Ada = result.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == "Ada No").Value;
}
```

But it didn't work either. How can I avoid this exception in this piece of code? How can I write if Ada No exists, work, if not don't work? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`FirstOrDefault` will return null if there is not any object which meets the condition. And the exception will be thrown when the code is trying to access a member of a reference type variable that is set to null. So, you must check if the object's value is null or not before accessing it.

You can use null-propagation operator if you are using C# 6.0:

```
myobject.Ada = result.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == "Ada No")?.Value;
```

Or if you are using lower versions:

```
var firstObj = result.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == "Ada No");

if(firstObj != null)
{
    myobject.Ada = firstObj.Value;
}
```

Comment: I don't think FirstOrDefault is the one throwing NullReferenceException. I think that result is the one being null.

Answer (score 2):

The other solution would be to check with Any if any member is existing that consists of Name equal to "Ada No"

Be aware that `result` isn't null either!

But the null propagation way would be less to write, so it depends on you preference how you want to read your code and if it is some performance critical piece of code

```
if(result != null && result.Any(m => m.Name == "Ada No"))
{
    myobject.Ada = result.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == "Ada No").Value;
}
```